# EF: Modeling ManytoOne and ManytoMany relationships on Derived Types in a Single Collection (Polymorphic Associations with different relationships)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, inheritance, relationship

I am working with Entity Framework 5.0.17 and I'm facing challenges when trying to model classes with inheritance and different types of relationships.

Here is my scenario:

I have a Business class that has a Users property:

```
public virtual ICollection<EmailUser> Users { get; set; } = new Collection<EmailUser>();
```

I then have two classes Employee and BusinessDirector that both inherit from EmailUser.

Employee has a many-to-one relationship with Business - a Business can have many Employees, but an Employee can only belong to one Business.

On the other hand, BusinessDirector has a many-to-many relationship with Business - a Business can have many BusinessDirectors and a BusinessDirector can belong to many Businesses.

My ultimate goal is to be able to add either an Employee or a BusinessDirector to the Business.Users collection and have Entity Framework correctly handle the relationships.

I'm having difficulty setting up the OnModelCreating method in the DbContext to correctly accommodate this situation. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to structure these classes, and how to configure Entity Framework to handle this scenario.

Is what I want even possible? Do I need to upgrade my version of EF for this to work?